# Laravel intersect wont get input

Tags: php, laravel, intersect

I have an intersect in my update method:

```
$inputs = $request->intersect('message','name','email','is_read');
```

If i send an update request where is_read=0 the intersect returns an empty array. Works fine with anything else (false, 1 etc)

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean that the whole array is empty (no keys for `message`, `name`, `email`) or only the `is_read` key is missing?

Comment: @LombaX on is_read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ALERT** 
Try to move to another implementation and stop using `intersect()` method, it will be removed from the future versions of Laravel: [Link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18695)

IF you mean that the `is_read` key is missing from the final array (and not the the whole array is empty, see my comment), this is because of the implementation of the `intersect()` method.

The `intersect` method simply wraps the `only()` method of the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class and do an `array_filter` over the result.

This is the implementation:

```
/**
 * Intersect an array of items with the input data.
 *
 * @param  array|mixed  $keys
 * @return array
 */
public function intersect($keys)
{
    return array_filter($this->only(is_array($keys) ? $keys : func_get_args()));
}
```

In your case, we can decompose the code as this:

**step1**

```
$results = $request->only('message','name','email','is_read');
```

At this point, `$results` is

```
Array
(
    [message] => message
    [name] => name
    [email] => email
    [is_read] => 0
)
```

However, at step2

**step2**

```
$filteredResults = array_filter($results);
```

The result becomes

```
Array
(
    [message] => message
    [name] => name
    [email] => email
)
```

And this is because of how `array_filter` works. It expect an array as the first parameter, then an optional callback (used to filter the array) and a flag.

From [php reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

What happens when no callback is provided (like in this case?)

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see [converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

If you look at the link [converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) you'll see that 0 (zero) is assumed to be FALSE and, for that reason, removed from the array.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description, i have updated my code, now instead of 0 i return a false as string and then convert that to a boolean false and it works that way